# Fraction field of $A[[t]]$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, power-series, valuation-theory

Let $A$ be a complete discrete valuation ring. (For example $A$ is the completion of the local ring of a curve at a point).

What is the fraction field of $A[[t]]$? Is it $\operatorname{Frac}(A)((t))$?

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140054/what-is-the-fraction-field-of-rx-the-power-series-over-some-integral-doma.

Comment: Ohhh didn't see it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the fraction field of $R[[x]]$, the power series over some integral domain?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140054/what-is-the-fraction-field-of-rx-the-power-series-over-some-integral-doma)