# some notation in field extension

Tags: ramification

I know $\mathbb{F}_3$ = $\mathbb{Z}$/3$\mathbb{Z}$ = {0,1,2}. But what does $\mathbb{F}_3$ ((X)) mean? And how can we find a totally tamely ramified extension and unramified extension of it respectively?

Comment: $\mathbf F_3((X))$ is the field of fractions of the ring of formal power series $$\mathbf F_3[[X]]$$ with coefficients in $\mathbf F_3$ – in other words the formal Laurent series with coefficients in $\mathbf F_3$.

Comment: Before studying ramifications you should first recall the notions of function fields, power series rings, number fields etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ring of formal Laurent series in one variable over a ring $R$ is denoted by $R((x))$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series). In your case, $R=\Bbb F_3$. For the relation with the fraction field of $R[[x]]$ see here:

[What is the fraction field of $R[[x]]$, the power series over some integral domain?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140054/what-is-the-fraction-field-of-rx-the-power-series-over-some-integral-doma)

Concerning tamely ramified and unramified extensions see [here](http://www.math.clemson.edu/~kevja/REU/2012/REU%20writeup-ExtLocalFcFields.pdf).

Comment: Thank you. It says that the extension is obtained by adjoining a primitive (p^f -1)st root of unity to K.