# Fraction field of $\mathbb Z_p[[X]]$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, power-series, principal-ideal-domains

We know that the fraction field $F:=\operatorname{Frac}(\mathbb Z_p[[X]])$ is **strictly** contained in the field of Laurent power series $\mathbb Q_p((X))$, thanks to  [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2035816?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) result of Gilmer. So my question is:

> Is it possible to describe explicitly the elements of $F$?

Some similar questions have been already asked here or on Mathoverflow. Maybe the most relevant is [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359941/computation-of-fraction-field-of-formal-series-over-the-integers?rq=1) regarding the explicit computation of the fraction field of $\mathbb Z[[X]]$. Someone suggests in the comments of the linked question that the problem with $\mathbb Z_p$ (instead of $\mathbb Z$) should be easier.

Some general necessary conditions are given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140054/what-is-the-fraction-field-of-rx-the-power-series-over-some-integral-doma) when the coefficients of the power series lie in any domain, but I'd like to find some sufficient conditions in the particular case of $\mathbb Z_p$.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to post this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation. The accepted answer is wrong. It is not true that a nonzero element of $\mathbb{Z}_p[[X]]$ is of the form $X^np^m\sum_k b_kX^k$ with $b_0\notin (p)$. For example, $p+X$ is not of this form. And indeed the inverse of $p+X$ is not in $\mathbb{Z}_p[[X]][X^{-1},p^{-1}]$: $$(p+X)^{-1}=\sum_k (-1)^k\frac{1}{p^{k+1}}X^k .$$
As in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/360155) to one of the questions you linked, by the Weierstrass preparation theorem it is enough to invert $p$ and all monic polynomials. However, this doesn't give a description of the fraction field in terms of the coefficients of the Laurent power series. I don't know if such a description exists.

Comment: $v(\sum_{n\ge 0} a_n x^n)= \inf_n v_p(a_n)$ is a discrete valuation, it extends to the fraction field $F$. It seems natural to consider the completion $F_v$ which may have a simpler description. The residue field is $\Bbb{F}_p((x))$ and uniformizer $p$ so it's probably $F_v=W(\Bbb{F}_p((x)))$

Comment: The completion $F_v$ is the ring of formal series $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n x^n$ with $\lim_{n\to \infty} |a_n|_p<\infty,\lim_{n\to -\infty} |a_n|_p=0$

Comment: You're absolutely right, I don't know how I missed this (although I had no memory of answering this question :D )

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$
Every element $f\in\mathbb{Z}_p[[x]]$ can be written as
$$
f(x) = p^e u(x) q(x)
$$
with $e \geq 0$, $u(x)\in \mathbb{Z}_p[[x]]^*$ and $q(x)\in \mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ monic.

This follows from the [Weierstrass preparation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_preparation_theorem#Formal_power_series_in_complete_local_rings).

Therefore every element $F \in \text{Frac}\left( \Z_p[[x]] \right)$ can be written as
$$
F =  \frac{f(x)}{q(x)}
$$
with $f(x)\in \Z_p[[x]]$ and $q(x) \in \Z_p[x]$.

Inverting $q(x)$ shows what kinds of bounds we can have on the coefficients $F_n$ of $F$, in particular $\limsup_{n \to \infty}\frac{v_p(F_n)}{n} < \infty$.

---

Another way to see this is to write
$$
F=\frac{1}{x^a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)},
$$
with $f(x)\in \Z_p[[x]]$, and  $x \nmid g(x)$, and
$$
g(x) = \sum g_i x^i = p^{e} + g_1x + g_2x^2\ldots
$$
with $c \geq 0$. Then
$$
p^{-e}g(x) = 1 + \frac{g_1}{p^r}x + \frac{g_2}{p^r}x^2 + \ldots
$$
and therefore
$$
h(x) = \frac{1}{p^{-r} g(x) } \in \Z_p[[\tfrac{x}{p^r}]].
$$
So $F = \frac{1}{p^e}\frac{1}{x^a} f(x) h(x)$ with
$$
h(x) \in \bigcup_{e=0}^\infty {\large{\Z_p}}\big[\big[\tfrac{x}{p^e}\big]\big].
$$